# SSL Handshake failure over SOCKS5 connection

Tags: go, socks, socks5

I am making a relay between the target server and me, the relay is the SOCKS5 proxy server.

But I do not understand why the SSL handshake fails when sending an HTTPS request, I mean I don't see anything odd in my code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/Pix4Devs/pix4lib/socks"
)

func main() {
    proxy := socks.ProxyCtx{
        IP:   "185.199.229.156",
        Port: 7492,
    }
    target := socks.TargetCtx{
        IP:   "google.com",
        Port: 443,
    }

    conn, err := socks.NewSocks5Client(time.Second * 3).Connect(proxy,false, socks.Auth{}, target); if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    tlsConn := tls.Client(conn, &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
    if err := tlsConn.Handshake(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if _, err := tlsConn.Write([]byte("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    reply := []byte{}
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := tlsConn.Read(buffer)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        reply = append(reply, buffer[:n]...)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(reply))
}
```

Comment: You send the request on `conn` not `tlsConn`.

Comment: @z3ntl3 What SteffenUllrich said is true. But that implies that `tlsConn.Handshake()` is working, but your description implies it is not.  So, where exactly is the actual failure occuring, and what is the actual error you are seeing?

Comment: @RemyLebeau yo it is indeed true that conn should be tlsCon (i forgot that), but the main problem happens on .Handshake method,  it returns this error:

2023/09/09 11:26:42 tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Comment: That error means the TLS client did not receive a TLS handshake from the target server. But the code looks fine to me. So you'll likely have to sniff the network traffic to figure out why you are not receiving what you are expecting.